# Defining large matrix with "big memory" package in R

Tags: r

I am using the big memory package and need to define a large matrix (20000 * 20000).

```
A <- big.matrix (20000 , 20000 , type ="double", init = 0)
```

Resulting in:

> Error: memory could not be allocated for instance of type big.matrix

My questions: 
(1.) Does the package enables a matrix of that size in general?
(2.) If not, are there any other options to create such a matrix in R?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have enough physical memory?

Comment: Please read the help file `?big.matrix`. There you will see "A standard, shared big.matrix is constrained to available RAM" whereas a "file-backed big.matrix may exceed available RAM by using hard drive space." For the second type, you need to specify the file backing. The vignette provides examples, including the example on page 1.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I specified the file backing. That solved it

Comment: @SkorpionYa, for the sake of other people going through a similar problem, would you care to post the code of your solution as an answer (see field below)?

Answer (score 0):

This answer espands on Imo's explanation of specifying file-backing.

Unfortunately, the current CRAN version of the package (4.5.36)  doesn't contain a vignette anymore, but thankfully it's possible to download [older versions](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bigmemory/) that contain it. For example, the vignette for version 4.5.28 contains the following piece of code:

```
x <- read.big.matrix("airline.csv", type="integer", header=TRUE, 
                      backingfile="airline.bin",
                      descriptorfile="airline.desc",
                      extraCols="Age")
```

If you wish to keep your working directory clean, you can use the `temppath()` and `tempdir()` functions. Here's one example:

```
temp_file <- gsub("/", "", tempfile(tmpdir = ""))
A <- big.matrix(
  20000 , 20000 , type ="double", init = 0,
  backingpath = tempdir(),
  backingfile = paste0(temp_file, ".bak"),
  descriptorfile = paste0(temp_file, ".desc"),
)
```